# Servlet Model 2 misunderstanding

Tags: model-view-controller, design-patterns, jakarta-ee, servlets

Good day. Having read about Model 2 architecture I got confused about some points.
For example my controller servlet url-pattern is `'*.perform'`.

1. How do I access the database and put the bean into the session if my jsp url does not correspond the servlet url-pattern?
2. If I've done the action, why do I use forward? The url remains the same `'actionName.perform'`
3. How should be the app designed for the servlet to process every page and forward to the corresponding JSP without processing it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The point of a front controller is that it intercepts all requests. You should never send a request to a JSP directly. Always to some `*.perform` URL. All your links and forms must poiunt to an `*.perform` URL.
2. The forward gives the control, at server-side to another resource. Once the controller servlet has finished its job, it gives the control to the JSP, which generates the markup. This all happens at server-side, and the browser knows nothing about this. It's absolutely normal for the URL to remain the same.
3. See 1. I don't understand what you mean by "without processing it again", though.